# Error message when a user enters more characters than max length on text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I return an error message to users when they try to go past the max length in a text area?

Is there a way for HTML to return an error to the user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="fieldname" maxlength="10">
```

You can use the `maxlenght` attribute to forbid entering more characters than intended. You will not need JS for this.

If you still want to use JS, then:

```
$("#myformid").keypress(function() {
    if($(this).val().length > 10) {
        //display your warinig the way you chose
   }
]
});
```

Comment: Im already doing this, but we want an error message to pop up if the user tries to enter more

Comment: You are then into requiring javascript. There are countless validation libraries out there.

Comment: @discodowney added js code to detect how many character are entered. I dont know, how you want to display you warining thou, so i left this part empty

Comment: The `(this).val().length` will never be greater than 10 since there is a limit on the input field. Needs to be `>= 10`

Comment: While this technically works, I think it's better to use the maxlength attribute value for the length conditional check as Muhammad suggested below for scalability.

Answer (score 3):

Sure this is possible!
First, count the entered characters and then print out the message you'd like to (here: "Characters left: X", the max length is 100 in my example).

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jk5h37r4/)!

---

**HTML:**

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id ="yourtextarea">
</textarea>

<div id="info"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#yourtextarea").keyup(function(){
    $("#info").text("Characters left: " + (100 - $(this).val().length));
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution for all input fields that has **MAXLENGTH attribute** defined, so that you *don't* have to apply **size** for each element.

```
$("input[maxlength], textarea[maxlength]").keyup(function () {
    var max = $(this).prop('maxlength');
    if ($(this).val().length > max) {
        alert('value must be less than ' + max + ' characters');
    }
});
```

Comment: IMO this is the best answer because it scales very nicely. Someone can just change the maxlength attribute size on the frontend and not worry about the underlying JS code.

Answer (score 0):

```
function check_length(my_form)
{
  maxLen = 50; // max number of characters allowed
  if (my_form.my_text.value.length >= maxLen) {
    var msg = "You have reached your maximum limit of characters allowed";
    alert(msg);
    my_form.my_text.value = my_form.my_text.value.substring(0, maxLen);
  }
}


<textarea onKeyPress=check_length(this.form); onKeyDown=check_length(this.form); name=my_text rows=4 cols=30></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code to validate user input without having to use Jquery.

```
<textarea id=txt onKeyUp=check() maxlength=10>
Abc
</textarea>
<div id=warning></div>

<script>
function check() {
    stringLength = document.getElementById('txt').value.length;
    if (stringLength >= 10) {
         document.getElementById('warning').innerText = "Maximum characters are 10"
    } else {
        document.getElementById('warning').innerText = ""
    }
}
</script>
```